# CreateFileA returns error 20, "The system cannot find the device specified" intermittently

Tags: c++, winapi, msbuild, createfile

I am debugging a custom exe during the compiling of my code using the msbuild exec task.

It runs the following code:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(szFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  Fatal(szFile, 1, "unable to open file (%x)", GetLastError());
```

szFile is the dll/exe that was compiled by msbuild, which is passed to program as an argument.

I am seeing the following error sometimes:

```
unable to open file (20)
```

After rebuilding the error doesn't happen again.  According the the windows codes, error code 20 is:

```
ERROR_BAD_UNIT20 (0x14)

The system cannot find the device specified.
```

I'm not sure what this mean though.  It doesn't seem to be that the file in question doesn't exist, because it does.  If it didn't the error code would be "2", I've tried.  Do you know what can cause this error?  Thanks.

Couple of things:

```
const char *szFile = nullptr;
...
szFile = argv[i]; // it loops over the arguments, parses them and finds the right argment for the file.
....
SetFileAttributes(szFile, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(szFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   Fatal(szFile, 1, "unable to open file (%x)", GetLastError());
```

Fatal() just does a printf of the file name and message.

Comment: Check if szFile variable contains correct value. Don't forget to escape '\' characters.

Comment: @Kostia: Escaping `\\` characters is only required when using string/character **literals**. At runtime a variable pointing to a string is interpreted as is. No escaping is required.

Comment: Still, check if szFile contains the correct value.

Comment: In particular, could you show the code that gets `szFile` out?

Comment: It looks like szFile does have the expected value.  Could this be a case of one process having a handle on the file in question while the createfile happens?  I'm not sure what would cause that, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the error code in hexadecimal (`%x`) rather than in decimal.

Error code 0x20 (32 decimal) is `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` ("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.")  So, yes, your guess about another process having the file open was correct.

In these circumstances, I suspect a race condition, possibly affected by virus scanning.  Consider having your code detect this particular error and retry after a short wait.

Comment: Thanks, is there a good way to detect what that process is causing this, either in C++ or  externally?

Comment: @user: Raymond Chen has a blog entry on this: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx)

Comment: In this situation (if you just want to figure out what's happening in your development environment, rather than putting a mechanism into your code for the end users) it might be simpler to use Process Monitor.  (Available for download from the MS web site.)

Comment: Download link: [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx).